# When running parallel="tests" from TestNG suit, then values from data provider is coming twice for the same field

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

For example- I have a username field in the application, here the username I am sending through a `dataProvider`.

Example- I am sending the username as "abc@yopmail.com"

When running my test as parallel, then data provider is populating username in the username field as "abc@yopmail.comabc@yopmail.com" (2 times the values is getting populated)

But when I am not running the tests as parallel all is fine and the "abc@yopmail.com" value is populated in the mentioned filed.

My Suit File is as follows:

```
    <suite name="Arc Facilities" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
        <test name="Login Test">
            <classes>
                <class name="com.arc.testcases.LoginTest" />
            </classes>
        </test>
    # In that way multiple tests are present
      </suite>
```

Please find below `dataProvider` declaration in the `testutils`:

```
@DataProvider(name = "dp",parallel = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The data provider runs twice in your case because in the XML runner parallel=tests that means Login Test will be invoked twice in 2 different threads.
You need to change parallel value to methods.

```
<suite name="Arc Facilities" parallel="methods" thread-count="1" data-provider-thread-count="2">
        <test name="Login Test">
            <classes>
                <class name="com.arc.testcases.LoginTest" />
            </classes>
        </test>
</suite>
```

***Note: change counts according to your needs.***

I think you're missing the difference between Test and Method, in TestNG if you wanna run test methods with @Test annotation in parallel then the relevant Key is methods, "tests" is relevant to  tag in the XML. In your case  is called twice according to thread-count=2, changing parallel to methods will run @Test methods in parallel.

**And check data-provider-thread-count parameter, it is important as well, by default it equals 1.
The dataproviderthreadcount multiplied by  the number of allowable threads per test method, which is set by the threadCount property.**

Comment: Thank you @Nael Marwan for looking into this, My suit contains multiple tests in the way I have given above, <Test 1></Test1>, <Test 2></Test2>, its just the formatting not allowing me to add the entire suit I have just given one example by giving a single test. Also dataproviderthreadcount  is provided in the suit, still the error exist.